# Walking a directory tree inside a Google Cloud Platform bucket in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

For directories on a local machine, the [`os.walk()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) method is commonly used for walking a directory tree in Python.

Google has a Python module ([`google.cloud.storage`](https://cloud.google.com/python/)) for uploading to and downloading from a [GCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) bucket in a locally-run Python script.

I need a way to walk directory trees in a GCP bucket. I browsed through the classes in the `google.cloud` Python module, but could not find anything. Is there a way to perform something similar to `os.walk()` on directories inside a GCP bucket?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is any os.walk() method for Google storage API out of the box. may be you can try to list the files under a bucket as found from https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html

The thing is, under the hood, Google storage doesn't looks at directories in the same way what we call as "directories" in linux. Its all files. So for example:
the object gs://your-bucket/abc/def.txt is just an object that happens to have "/" characters in its name. There is no "abc" directory; just a single object with the given name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No such function exists in the GCS library. However, GCS can list objects by prefix, which is usually sufficiently equivalent:

```
from google.cloud import storage

bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket(bucket_name)
for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix="dir1/"):
  print(blob.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket_name')

for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix=''):
   # Download the file
    with open(blob.name, 'wb') as file_obj:
        client.download_blob_to_file(blob, file_obj)

   # You logic on the file
   # logic goes here

   # Remove the local file
   os.remove(blob.name)
```